# Dropping frames from the wireless channel

Tags: omnet++, inet

Is there any ways to drop a specific frame on the wireless channel in INET? For example, I want frame `frame_name_123` that is sent on the air from node1 to node2 to be dropped so that node2 never receive it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What should node2 see? Nothing (i.e., as if frame_name_123 was never transmitted)? A busy channel (maybe the frame was jammed)? Half of the frame (some collision occurred)? Should it be able to notice that there was a frame or not?

Comment: Yes, I mean as if `frame_name_123` was never transmitted.

Comment: in that case I'd probably recommend writing code for it in the implementation of node1 (i.e., instructing it to drop the desired frames). I think for this case, coding is required (i.e., you can't do it directly from the OMNeT++ execution environment), but I might be wrong about that.